# Trim the value of the result produced by using currency converter web service

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know that if I am using a currency converter web service and showing the result using javascript, then how will I be able to trim the result upto 2 decimal places.?
I have tried

```
success: function(data) {
            $('#currency_converter_result').html(data.d.toFixed(2));
}
```

But it is not showing the result.Please point out where am i going wrong ? Thanks
This the javascript i am using I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
          $('#btnConvert').click(function()
          {
              var amount = $('#txtAmount').val();
              var from = $('#ddlfrom').val();
              var to = $('#ddlto').val();
              $.ajax(
              {
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService.asmx/CurrencyConversion",
                data: "{amount:" + amount + ",fromCurrency:'" + from + "',toCurrency:'" + to + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#currency_converter_result').html(data.d);
                }
              }
          }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please include an example result that the service returns?

Comment: try Number(data.d).toFixed(2)

Comment: @matthew mcveigh I tried doing this but still the same problem- $('#currency_converter_result').val(parseFloat($('#currency_converter_result').val()).toFixed(2)).html(data.d);

Comment: seems like what you want is: `$('#currency_converter_result').html(parseFloat(data.d).toFixed(2));` we need to know what data looks like to give you a better answer

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh I am getting the result in this format- "61.8199802 Indian rupees".
But I want to trim the decimal values upto 2 places i.e. I want to show 61.81 upon clicking the convert button.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you could regard the currency as a string and simply trim off all the characters after the index of a decimal point + 2.

For example:

```
var precision = 2;
var currency = "$100.4996";
var trimmed = currency.slice( 0, currency.lastIndexOf(".") + 1 + precision ); 
// The additional 1 is to start the slice after the decimal point.
```

References -

- [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)